# C# How to group list items by weeks

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I have the following code that i use to group a list of objects(Income) by month, and return a dictionary as follows

```
List<Income> allIncome = GetAllIncome();
        Dictionary<string, int> monthlyIncome = allIncome.GroupBy(i => i.DateCreated.Month)
            .ToDictionary(i => i.Key.ToString(), i=> i.Sum( x => x.Amount));
        return monthlyIncome;
```

where The `Income` Model is below

```
Income:
    public string Name{get;set;};
    public DataTime DateCreated{get;set;}
```

Im still trying to figure out how to do the implementation for weeks. That is how to group income items by week instead of months. Any ideas please..

Comment: Ad: you can use search engine to find answers... Google, Yahoo, Rambler, Baidu, Bing - https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+get+week+number+from+date or https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+groupby+week+number

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of grouping by `Month` group by a method result of `GetWeekOfYear`. Here's the reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.getweekofyear(v=vs.110).aspx